# Setup of secure storage in a VM of Ubuntu w/ ecryptfs?

Tags: encryption, ecryptfs, virtualization

What are the steps to setup secure storage in a Ubuntu VM, preferably by using ecryptfs.

Comment: **Virtualbox** has the option of encryption for your virtual machine(s). Have you already gave that a look? If so, then how about downloading a **pre-setup Ubuntu VM w/ ecryptfs**? I brought these two options up because they are the simplest, not because I didn't read your question! =P